# Is it possible to "jump" to another address when script detects jmp?

Tags: ida, idapython

here is the original C++ source code of the executable that I've created to do simple RE

```
#include <iostream>

void myFunction() {

    printf("Hello!");
}

int main()
{
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

When I disassembled my executable in IDA, this is the first block that I see
[image]

With the address being 0x4112c1
[image]

I've created a simple IDAPython script to find out what is the next address after the **jump _main_0**

```
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *
from idc import *

cursor = 0
start_addr = 0
end_addr = 0
print("----------Starting python script----------\n")
for func in Functions():
    name = get_func_name(func)
    if "_main" == name:
        start_addr = get_func_attr(func, FUNCATTR_START)
        end_addr = get_func_attr(func, FUNCATTR_END)
        print("Start: 0x%x, End: 0x%x" %(start_addr, end_addr))

cursor = start_addr
print('0x%x %s' % (cursor, generate_disasm_line(cursor, 0)))
cur_addr = next_head(cursor, end_addr)
print("Next Head: 0x%x" %cur_addr)
print("---------Exiting Python script------")
```

And this is the following output:

```
----------Starting python script----------

Start: 0x4112c1, End: 0x4112c6
0x4112c1 jmp     _main_0
Next Head: 0xffffffff
---------Exiting Python script------
```

I have 2 questions I would like to ask:

1. May I ask why isn't the address of the next head 0x411930 (which is the address of _main_0, as shown in the screenshot below) ?
   [image]
2. Is it possible to make the script go to the address of the mentioned function when it detects a jump statement? (because I thought next head will do the trick)

***Disclaimer: I'm kinda new to RE and IDAPython so do bear with me if I ask too much*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May I ask why isn't the address of the next head 0x411930 (which is the address of _main_0, as shown in the screenshot below) ?

From [IDAPython docs](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/):

> next_head(ea, maxea=4294967295)
>
> Get next defined item (instruction or data) in the program

That will give you the next defined item after the address passed in `ea` no matter what instruction is at `ea`.

> Is it possible to make the script go to the address of the mentioned function when it detects a jump statement? (because I thought next head will do the trick)

Of course it is possible. One way to do that is to call `ida_xref.get_first_cref_from` and extract that address from its output. Probably there are some better ways to do that, but this one should work.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your suggestion! That function works for me and it's good for me (for now :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, and is just a slightly expanded version of an old function `GetTarget` I have.  It's very low-tech (simple API usage only), and (probably) will only work correctly for the x86/64 platform where all conditional jump mnemonics start with `j` and no mnemonic starts with `j` that isn't a jump of some type.

The alternative (which I also have) using NN_* code is harder to grasp for a beginner.

```
def GetTarget(ea):
    mnem = GetMnem(ea)
    if not mnem:
        return BADADDR
    
    opType0 = GetOpType(ea, 0)
    if mnem == "jmp" or mnem == "call" or mnem[0] == "j":
        if opType0 != o_near and opType0 != o_mem:
            print("Can't follow opType0 " + opTypeAsName(opType0))
            return BADADDR
        else:
            return GetOperandValue(ea, 0)

    if NextHead(ea) == ea + ItemSize(ea) and isFlow(GetFlags(NextHead(ea))):
        return NextHead(ea)

def opTypeAsName(n):
    for item in [x for x in dir(idc) if x.startswith('o_')]:
        if getattr(idc, item) == n: return item
```

Since the way I used to code is really a little embarrassing, here is the same code in *correct pythonic idapython 7*

```
def GetTarget7(ea):
    mnem = idc.print_insn_mnem(ea)
    if not mnem:
        return idc.BADADDR
    
    opType0 = idc.get_operand_type(ea, 0)
    if mnem == "jmp" or mnem == "call" or mnem[0] == "j":
        if opType0 != o_near and opType0 != o_mem:
            print("Can't follow opType0 " + opTypeAsName(opType0))
            return idc.BADADDR
        else:
            return idc.get_operand_value(ea, 0)

    if idc.next_head(ea) == ea + idc.get_item_size(ea) and \
            idc.is_flow(idc.get_full_flags(idc.next_head(ea))):
        return idc.next_head(ea)
```

*see [my github](https://github.com/sfinktah/sfida) for vim ultisnips auto-expanding 6 to 7 idapython conversion, and idapython syntax file*